# Atualizar componente React com window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, react

Sou iniciante no React e estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho três componentes `extends Component`que preciso que se comuniquem.

São eles uma NavBar e dois conteúdos estáticos.

O conteúdo da NavBar (texto e ícones) são alterados conforme o conteúdo (componente) que é carregado.

A solução que eu achei para atualizar a NavBar foi o `window.localStorage`já que são não posso deixar os conteúdos como componentes filhos da NavBar.

O `render()` da NavBar está condicional para cada item do `localStorage`.

O item do `localStorage` está sendo atualizado normalmente porém ele não é renderizado na tela.
Tem alguma maneira de se alterar `state` dos `components`que são irmãos e não filhos para não precisar usar o `localStorage`?

Comment: posta o código que você fez. Fica melhor pra opinar

Answer (score 0):

**Não é possível** alterar o `state` dos `components` que são **irmãos**, pois o React lida com dados unidirecionais.

Veja o seguinte esquema para entender como React lida com dados entre componentes:

[image: Dados são passados do componente pai para o componente filho em ReactJS, dados são direcionais.]

Note que os dados não são passados entre os componentes irmãos, mas sim recebidos pelo componente **pai** através das `props`.

No momento em que os dados são alterados no componente pai através do `setState`, em seguida o ReactJS chama o método `render()` do componente pai (e consequentemente de seus filhos com os dados atualizados).

Uma possível abordagem é criar um componente 'pai' dos componentes que armazena os dados que seus filhos irão utilizar. Assim, é possível passar para os filhos as funções que manipulam esses dados (somente o próprio componente deve alterar seu `state`).

Abaixo segue um exemplo genérico de como isso seria possível: o componente pai possui uma variável `numero` que é alterada por um filho:

```
class PaiDeTodos extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { numero: 123 }
}

alterarNumero = (novoNumero) => {
    this.setState({numero: novoNumero});
}

  render () {
    return <Navbar/>
           <ConteudoEstatico this.props.alterarNumero=alterarNumero>
  }
}
```

Componente filho recebeu através das `props` a função alterarNumero, que será chamada no clique do botão e por alterar o `state` do pai, causará a chamada do método `render()` do pai:

```
class ConteudoEstatico extends React.Component {

  cliqueBotao = () => {
    this.props.alterarNumero(555);
  }

  render () {
    return <button onClick={this.cliqueBotao}>Clique aqui.<button/>
  }
}
```